# telegram google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

Знаете ли вы, как можно отправить ответ из Google sheets в телеграм?

Например, если кто-то сделал запрос, я бы сразу ответил на него из Google Sheets, набрав сообщение в ячейке таблицы.

Мой бот написан на javaScript, возможно, эта функция может это сделать.

```
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi there");
}

function doPost(e) {
  // this is where telegram works
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
  var answer = "Hi, " + name + " wait an answer  " + text;
  sendText(id,answer);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,answer]);
```

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Comment: спасибо! перевел

Comment: Первое, можете упрерется в ограничение google scripts по кол-ву вызовов внешних апи.
Второе надо настроить саму таблицу, если это не автоматический ответ.
Кто-то написал - добавили строку в гугл файл с пустым полем для ответа и состояние отправки = 0
На гугл страницу нарисовать кнопку "отправить новые ответы"
Под кнопкой функция google scripts пройдётся по списку ответов, выберет все где состояние = 0, и циклом отправит всем и изменит состояние. Это как пример, который первый в голову пришёл если отправлять ответ с гугл таблицы.